# check ping update for bulk number of machines

Tags: shell-script, regular-expression

I got bulk number of machines which I need to cron to check the availability in every one hour so. I got nearly 1000 machine which are split between 4-5 name series followed by number for each node. Say from ab1000 to ab1200, from bs3000 to bs3892, from zx7800 to zx8900 etc. Currently I'm using a simple ping script as I can't keep any software on these nodes to monitor (I don't have approval for that). So in my code I'm calling the file where I update all the machine names one by one( trust me I need to do this everyday since the machine names happens very frequently) and wondering if I can use regex to mention the machines as it'll ease my life a lot. Say for eg: ab1*,zx[7-8]* etc. I tried to use the same in the input file but didn't help much. Also one more issue in this is,sometimes one or two machines are down permanently and I don't need to count everytime. So I need to keep it as excluded in my alert list.

Also let me know if there is anything else I can make the alert more robust like alert to give list as 3/300 sx are down with machine names sz7701,7702,7703

```
cat /tmp/node.txt

zx7800
zx7801
zx7802
.....
....
zx8900
bs3000
bs3001

cat nodecheck.sh

for node in `cat /tmp/node.txt`
do
 count=0
 count=$(ping -c 3 $node | grep "100%packet loss"|wc -l)
 if [ $count -ne 0 ]
 then
  echo "$node" >> /tmp/nodedown.txt
 fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list of the names you want to monitor. Either you maintain this list manually or extract the list from where someone else maintains the list of the machines that are supposed to be running.

You can simplify a few things. The `ping` command already returns an exit status, you can use it. Also you don't need redirection for each echo, once per loop is enough. This has the added benefit that the file is initialized and doesn't contain the lines from the last run.

```
for node in $(cat /tmp/node.txt); do
  if ! ping -c 3 $node &> /dev/null; then
    echo "$node"
  fi
done > /tmp/nodedown.txt
```

If you want a statistic, you can either count them, or you use `wc` to count the lines in the two files.

```
echo "$(wc -l < /tmp/nodedown.txt) / $(wc -l < /tmp/node.txt)"
```

Comment: thanks RalfFriedl.Wondering if I can use regex like zx76* or bs[3-4]* etc with ping command so that I don't need to keep a separate list for the machine names

Comment: A pattern is always matched against an existing list. For example. if you use a pattern for filenames, it is checked against the list of existing files.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

- [fping](http://www.fping.org/) is like ping, but explicitly designed for pinging multiple hosts.
- [whatsup](https://linux.die.net/man/1/whatsup) is a utility designed to monitor machines being up or down.